# make a process foreground and print to screen

Tags: python, bash

I am running multiple processes in the terminal like:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 
do 
python my_script.py $i   > /dev/null 2>&1 &
done
```

However, sometimes I would like to check its process and probably do

```
fg %1
```

In this case, when I check the process, instead of letting the process printing to the > /dev/null. I would like it to screen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Then don't modify where stdout is going. Defaultly it should go to the screen.

Comment: however, when the process is running in the background. I requires that its output not to print on the screen

Comment: Maybe instead use a terminal multiplexor like `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: If you want to see the output, it can't be discarded into /dev/null. Either write the data to a real file that you can examine later, or write to a different (pseudo)terminal, which is what `tmux` or `screen` facilitates.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot write it to a file.... since it prints a lot a lot of stuffs out, it would crush the hard drive.... for screen, since I am usually parallelizing a lot... I am not sure if that creating a screen for each and single one runs is reasonable.... I do not know about what tmux do yet though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect your python script output to some consuming process, which will be either (1) swallow chunk of data or (2) print it to stdout. The consumer can be configured to switch between two modes in runtime with process signals. See example implementation here: [here](https://github.com/legeyda/snippets/blob/master/switch_output.sh)

Comment: Very elegant solution.